# How to rename startup disk?

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I'm running the codes below to rename the startup disk, to perform some procedures
my question is if after performing these procedures I can rename the disk to its name "Original"

that is, I have a disk named "Big Sur" and running the codes below it is renamed to: "Apple HD"
but soon after performing the other tasks it returns the name to: Big Sur I tried to store the name in a variable but this does not work since the startup disk is renamed at runtime to "Apple HD".

```
tell application "Finder" to set diskName to name of startup disk
set newName to "Apple HD"

tell application "Finder" 
to set newName to diskName
end tell
```

Comment: **tell application "Finder" to set name of startup disk to "Apple HD"**

Comment: I want the disk name to return to its original name at the end of the process, but the disk can have any name because it will run on more than one computer, it wouldn't always be Big Sur and Apple HD.

Comment: It is not clear what you want in the end. You have stored original disk name in the **diskName** variable, so you can restore later the name of the disk using **tell application "Finder" to set name of startup disk to diskName**

Comment: But the diskName variable receives the value of the newName variable in the second block of code. ```tell application "Finder" 
to set newName to diskName
end tell```

Comment: See the answer to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- save original name into the variable, to restore it later
tell application "Finder" to set diskName to name of startup disk

-- rename startup disk
tell application "Finder" to set name of startup disk to "Apple HD"

-- perform some procedures here

-- rename startup disk back to original name
tell application "Finder" to set name of startup disk to diskName
```